# How to filter out "_id" from mongodb C driver results

Tags: c, mongodb

I have been going through the documentation and I'm still lost on how to filter out `_id` results from mongodb using the C driver.
I essentially want this functionality but I'm not sure

```
db.collection.find({"test":"pass"},{_id: false});
```

How would I include that projection in C?

```
cursor = mongoc_collection_find (collection, MONGOC_QUERY_NONE, 0, 0, 0, query, NULL, NULL);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of trial and error I was able to finally add flags to a search query.  For anyone else here is the format for appending the No id flag to a MongoC search.

> bson_t *field = bson_new();
>
> BSON_APPEND_INT32(field,"_id", 0);

to a search pattern like

> cursor = mongoc_collection_find (collection, MONGOC_QUERY_NONE, 0, 0, 0, query, field, NULL);